# How to v-model 2 values?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I was using buefy `<b-autocomplete>` component and there is one property called `v-model` which is binding values to the input field

now I wanna bind Full Name into the field but the data consist with `list[index].first_name` and `list[index].last_name`, and the `index` is from a `v-for` loop.

Since `v-model` cannot bind a function (it has specific index so I cannot just concat it on `computed` then pass it on) so it's either `v-model="list[index].first_name"` or `v-model="list[index].last_name"`

How do I make it bind's these two?

Comment: In short, you can't: imagine this, a user provides the string `John Derrick Andersen` in the input field, which part of it is the first name, and which part of it is the last name? It is a one way road: you can construct the full name from the data, but cannot deconstruct it if a user provides an ambiguous input. All you can is to create a component for each input field (by index), and in that component a computed property that joins the first and last name with a space, and bind that property to `v-model`.

Comment: @Terry Should be another way around. I don't need to add any thing into the `list`, so the `first_name` and `last_name` is fixed because its provided by the `list`. In short, the v-model just intended to display the name on input field since I wanna use `<b-autocomplete>` like a dropdown menu but also can searching the names.

Comment: If you don’t intend for the user input to change the internal stores of the first and last name, just bind the variables to the value attribute.

Comment: I do not have much time to write an answer so I'll leave a demo in this comment. Remember that a computed property is just a getter and setter which gets cached. Use `get()` and `set()` to do what you want, here's the idea: https://jsfiddle.net/e93kL4vL/

Comment: I believe the [Object array](https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation/autocomplete) example from the Buefy docs examples should help you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need a settable computed for full name, and you can v-model that. You just have to decide on a rule for where extra spaces go and what to do if there is no space.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Joe',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  },
  computed: {
    fullName: {
      get() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        const m = newValue.match(/(\S*)\s+(.*)/);

        this.firstName = m[1];
        this.lastName = m[2];
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  First: {{firstName}}<br>
  Last: {{lastName}}<br>
  Full Name: <input v-model="fullName">
</div>
```

Comment: In the example you provide,an logic error occurs when delete the first name

Comment: You have to decide (and implement) what it will do. I tried a few approaches and I like this one, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i get the question,but i am assuming that you have a list of names and last names and you want to give the ability to user to change those proprties of list.For more [See the example in action](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/qad06wye/)

**The "html" part**

```
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="item in list" :key="list.id">
    <input type="text" :value="item.name" @input="changeList($event, item.id, 'name')">
    <input type="text" :value="item.last_name" @input="changeList($event, item.id, 'last-name')">
    Your full name is {{item.name}} {{item.last_name}}
    <hr>
  </template>
</div>
```

**The "javascript(vue)" part**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list: [
      { id: 1, name: "name1", last_name: 'last_name 1' },
      { id: 2, name: "name2", last_name: 'last_name 2' },
      { id: 3, name: "name3", last_name: 'last_name 3' },
      { id: 4, name: "name4", last_name: 'last_name 4' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    changeList(event, id, property) {
        let value = event.target.value

      for (item of this.list) {
        if (item.id === id) {
            if(property === 'name') {
            item.name = value
          }else if (property === 'last-name') {
            item.last_name = value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's been said you can't use 2 values in `v-model`
But if you want to use `<b-autocomplete>` that means you already have the data and you can compute it in any way you want.

If you have an array of user objects (with firstname and lastname for example) you can do something like:

```js
data() {
  return {
    users: [
      //...
    ],
    computedUsers: [],
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.users.forEach(user => {
    this.computedUsers.push(user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname)
  })
}
```

and use this new array in the `filteredDataArray` (from the [Buefy autocomplete example](https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation/autocomplete))

[Fiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/yzky8469/)