# Binding two or more data to a form input in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, model-binding

I was considering having more than one value in a `vue` `form input binding`

Below is a sample of my code.

```
<template> 
  <div> 
    <label for=""> Employee </label>
    <input class="form-control-plaintext" v-model="asset.current_status.user.surname" type= "text" readonly name="surname">
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
  data(){
    return:{
      asset:{},
    }
  },

  methods:{
     getAsset(){
        axios.get('/api/assets/'+this.id)
          .then ( response => {
            this.asset = response.data.data[0].data; 
            this.toFill = this.asset()
            this.assetForm.fill(this.toFill)
           })
        },
  },

   mounted(){
        this.getAsset();
    }
</script>
```

The `v-model` currently accepts and displays one value of surname, I believe it possible to include another value `asset.current_status.user.last_name` to the `v-model` inline but can't currently get things right.

Comment: Do you trying to display both values or one which is filled?

Comment: I tried using a `+` to concatenate both values inside the `v-model` attribute but it throws an error.

Comment: I'd suggest concating both props after you get data and before displaying it, so that v-model get's only one binding

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50261087/12767586) your question?

Comment: use computed function ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template> 
  <div> 
    <label for=""> Employee </label>
    <input class="form-control-plaintext" :value="showAssignedUser()" type= "text" readonly name="surname">
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
  data(){
    return:{
      asset:{},
    }
  },

  methods:{
     getAsset(){
        axios.get('/api/assets/'+this.id)
          .then ( response => {
            this.asset = response.data.data[0].data; 
            this.toFill = this.asset()
            this.assetForm.fill(this.toFill)
           })
        },

    showAssignedUser(){
        return `${this.asset.current_status.user.surname}` + ' '+ `${this.asset.current_status.user.first_name}`
    },

  },

  mounted(){
     this.getAsset();
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `computed` property like this:

```
computed: {
    surname () {
         if (this.asset.current_status.user.last_name 
             && this.asset.current_status.user.surname) {
       
         return this.asset.current_status.user.last_name 
                + this.asset.current_status.user.surname
         }

         return '' // or whatewer else you need...
    }
}
```

And set `v-model="surname"`.

Read more about [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Also if you need to edit that input you will need `get()` and `set()`.
You can check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260374/how-to-v-model-2-values/50261087#50261087) for that.

Good luck!

Comment: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined"`

Comment: This error is because of nested object values, more you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345740/error-in-render-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined-vue/59346777#59346777).

Comment: Your code isn't wrong, but it executes the else block even though `this.asset` isset and can be displayed on the template. I found a solution

Comment: Did you tried something like this: `if (this.asset && this.asset.current_status && this.asset.current_status.user.last_name && this.asset.current_status.user.surname`?

Comment: for real, yes. it returned false.